# Expand Youtube video when the play button is clicked

Tags: youtube

I want to embed videos on my tumblr http://wealhwealh.tumblr.com/, but the block sizes is 250x141. When I start a video, it looks like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/pp4p1efw/

I want the video to expand when the user clicks on play, or on hover. Thanks!

Here's the tumblr html for video:

```
<video tabindex="-1" class="video-stream html5-main-video" style="width: 250px; height: 141px; left: 0px; top: 0px; transform: none;" src="blob:https%3A//www.youtube.com/48ae4f07-e8b1-4cf0-8890-5a896b7c1c82"></video>
```

Comment: You mean expand to fullscreen? Or just bigger?

Comment: Just bigger, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/5BKYZ/4/. The code works but not on tumblr, since it's not the same thing. I want it to work on every video I post, not only one. The thing is: the code is for this video only (var youtube_video_id = "Cgovv8jWETM";) but I want it to be global.